# "Play a friend!" Quest Minimum Time Required

Tags: hearthstone

Recently Blizzard introduced the new "Play a friend!" quest, where a player is supposed to challenge another friend and play a game to get the 80 gold for both of the players. However, I've also heard that Blizzard has set a turn/time minimum quota as to prevent players from conceding at turn 1.

**Has anyone been able to find out the minimum time/turn required to finish the quest, and if yes what is it?**

Comment: Conceding a lot of games will get you "soft banned" from giving credit to quests. Other than that there is a known bug for quests to not take credit, if a player conceded. Win a regular match after that and you might have 2 games credited towards a quest.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to both play aggressive decks and ignore any kind of minion trading? The game could be over by turn 5/6 with both players just playing minions, hit face, end turn. You could be done in 1 minute easy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to play until someone dies with lethal damage being dealt to them. That's the only way I've received the gold for it

Comment: so there is not a specific time limit, but u just have to kill one of the heroes. What if nxt turn you/your friend has lethal one of u decide to concede to avoid wasting time?

Answer (score -2):

The player with the quest has to initiate the challenge, or else neither player will receive the 80 gold.

Comment: I do know this, but I am not asking for this. What I'm looking for is the specified time required to complete the quest.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me! It's a valid answer to the question so I don't see any reason for the downvotes.